# Ionic link does not work with Ionic v2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

When I run ionic link command inside ionic project folder I got following error message

"You cannot run this command unless you are in an Ionic Project folder"

My system info.

Cordova CLI: 6.3.1
Gulp version: CLI version 1.2.1
Gulp local: Local version 3.9.1
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-beta.11
Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0-beta.36
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.19
OS: Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
 
Node Version: v6.4.0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use following command to setup app linking with Ionic IO.

> ionic io init

this will update ionic.config.json with app_id and generate .io-config.json file with app_id and api_key.

Comment: Didn't work for me. File was generated but it still says I'm not in a valid ionic folder

Comment: Works like a charm

Answer (score 4):

```
ionic io init
```

is no longer available in cli 3. Create a new app from apps.ionic.io dashboard and then run

```
ionic link
```

which will list down apps from your ionic.io account and let you choose an app to which you want to link your local app. You have to run 'ionic login' if you haven't done so already.